# Trigger warning: created with compilation errors

Tags: database, oracle, triggers

i have this trigger and it says Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.
can you give me quick advice?

```
 /
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER type_check
  BEFORE INSERT ON carrs
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :new.weight > 3500 
  THEN
    :new.type := 'nakladne';
  ELSE
    :new.type := 'osobne';
  END IF;
END;
/
```

edit: i still got the same warning

edit: here is table definition

```
create table carrs (
 id_Car Integer not null,
 id_board_unit Integer not null,
 id_evc_numbers Integer not null,
 id_owner Integer,
 weight Integer not null );
```

here are the errors:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
4/5      PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.TYPE'
6/5      PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.TYPE'
```

Comment: I don't know what tool you use, but in mine (PLSQL Developer), I can open the trigger, compile it and actually see what error message there is. Is there any way you can get some more info?

Comment: Does your `carrs` table have a column called `type`? Can you add the table definition to the question?

Comment: Well, now I'm very confused about what your goal might be.  Your trigger is trying to assign a value to the `type` column in your `carrs` table.  But you don't have any columns in the table that are even close to `type`.  You don't even have any `varchar2` columns in your table.  What is it that you are hoping your trigger will do?  Are you really trying to update the `type` column in some other table?

Comment: so i have this atribute `weight` and i want to everytime when INSERT INTO is done check it, create new column and if `weight > 3500` set atribute too `nakladne` else `osobne`

Comment: You don't want a trigger to create a new column in your table.  You really, really don't.  If you want to add a new column to your table, you'd do that once, via an `ALTER TABLE` statement.  Your trigger could then be used to populate the data for the new column for newly added rows.  You'd probably need to do a separate `UPDATE` statement after the `ALTER TABLE` to populate the data for existing rows.

Comment: I'm newbie in this, started day ago. If you could show me how it's done i would be grateful @JustinCave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using SQL*Plus, type `show errors` after getting that warning to display the list of syntax errors that were reported.  It's far easier to diagnose problems when you know what they are rather than guessing.

At a minimum, your references to the `:new` pseudorecord need to include the colon prefix `:new` rather than `new`.  The assignment operator in PL/SQL is also `:=` not `=`.  So, at a minimum, you'd want something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER type_check
  BEFORE INSERT ON carrs
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :new.weight > 3500 
  THEN
    :new.type := 'nakladne';
  ELSE
    :new.type := 'osobne';
  END IF;
END;
```

There may be additional errors as well.  If there are, type `show errors` and edit your question to include them.

If you wish to add a new column named `type` to your table, you would do that before creating your trigger.  That's not a particularly good name for a column, though, since `type` is also a reserved word in Oracle.  I'd choose something more meaningful like, say, `carr_type`.  You'd have to specify how large the strings the new column would need to hold when creating it.  I'll guess that you want space for 10 characters

```
ALTER TABLE carrs
  ADD( carr_type VARCHAR2(10 CHAR) );
```

You then probably want to `UPDATE` your table to populate the new column for your existing data

```
UPDATE carrs
   SET carr_type = (case when weight > 3500
                         then 'nakladne'
                         else 'osobne'
                      end)
```

before creating your trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER type_check
  BEFORE INSERT ON carrs
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :new.weight > 3500 
  THEN
    :new.carr_type := 'nakladne';
  ELSE
    :new.carr_type := 'osobne';
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: You are my new-born hero, hope you do well, have a nice day :-) again thank you so much for your time @justin